# error sending multiple files using client sockets architecture in python

Tags: python, sockets

I am learning the `socket programming` client server architecture in python. I made this program to send multiple files one by one from client to server. The client program queries the user to type the name of the file and then sends this name to server, where server opens a new file with that name in append+binary mode. But apparently the server creates a new file only the first time but not the other times. it simply appends the next files in the existing file. Please take a look.

```
#server.py
from socket import *

HOST = ''
PORT = 32000
ADDRESS = (HOST, PORT)
BUFF_SIZE = 1024

tcpServerSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcpServerSocket.bind(ADDRESS)
tcpServerSocket.listen(5)
print("waiting for connection..")
client, addr = tcpServerSocket.accept()
print("connected with {}".format(addr))
name = client.recv(BUFF_SIZE).decode()
while True:
    if not name:
        break
    f = open(name, 'ab')
    data = client.recv(BUFF_SIZE)
    while data:
        f.write(data)
        data = client.recv(BUFF_SIZE)
    f.close()
    name = client.recv(BUFF_SIZE)
    name = name.decode()

tcpServerSocket.close()
```

and this is client.py

```
from socket import *

HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 32000
ADDRESS = (HOST, PORT)
BUFF_SIZE = 1024

clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect(ADDRESS)
while True:
    name = input("please enter file name: \n")
    clientSocket.send(name.encode())
    if not name:
        break
    f = open(name, 'rb')
    data = f.read(BUFF_SIZE)
    while data:
        clientSocket.send(data)
        data = f.read(BUFF_SIZE)
    f.close()
    choice = input("Do you wanna send another file: y/n ?")
    if choice.lower() != 'y':
        clientSocket.send("".encode())
        break

clientSocket.close()
```

I want to know is there a flush method like function which closes the existing file/stream completely and creates a new one every time.

Answer (score 0):

I thing here is the problem. I didnt try it though. name the new file INSIDE the While true loop

```
#server.py
from socket import *

HOST = ''
PORT = 32000
ADDRESS = (HOST, PORT)
BUFF_SIZE = 1024

tcpServerSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcpServerSocket.bind(ADDRESS)
tcpServerSocket.listen(5)
print("waiting for connection..")
client, addr = tcpServerSocket.accept()
print("connected with {}".format(addr))

while True:
    name = client.recv(BUFF_SIZE).decode()
    if not name:
        break
    f = open(name, 'ab')
    data = client.recv(BUFF_SIZE)
    while data:
        f.write(data)
        data = client.recv(BUFF_SIZE)
    f.close()
    name = client.recv(BUFF_SIZE)
    name = name.decode()

tcpServerSocket.close()
```